# Using Google Maps Api in Backbone

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

I am just starting to program in javascript and backbone. I am trying to display a search box, a google map, and the results of a search (that geocodes a street address)on a template in Backbone. I am using the google documentation here, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

I am not able to get the map to render in the template, I am also not seeing any error messages in the Developer Tools console. I think it has something to do with the initialize function. I have tried what seems like a 100 potential configurations in this area. Any guidance would be helpful.

Here is the index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DateNite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=THISISWHEREMYKEYWOULDGO&sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/sha1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dn-container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DateNite</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills inverse">
      <li class="active"><a href="#current" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#map" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="#twitter" data-toggle="tab">Tweet</a></li>
    </ul>
    </br>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="current">a</div>  
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="map">Google</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="twitter">Tweet</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my template:

```
<div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" value="Portland, OR">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" class="geocode btn btn-success">
</div>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#map-canvas { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Here is my view:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#map', // every Backbone view has an associated DOM element

  template: require('../../templates/map.hbs'),

  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    this.render();
  },

  render: function () {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'onload', this.initialize);
    var context = {}
    context.businesses = this.model.get('businesses') || {};
    this.$el.html(this.template(context));
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5200, 122.6819);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    "click .geocode": "codeAddress",
  },

  codeAddress: function() {
    console.log("Button Clicked");
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Search was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  },

});

module.exports = MapView;
```

Comment: You attached your view to the `#map` element, but i can't find it in your html code ?

Comment: Hello Akaryarthrh its towards the bottom, <div class="tab-pane fade" id="map">Google</div>

Answer (score 1):

This might be the reason:

Below line

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

in `MapView's` `initialize` method is fetching an element `map-canvas` which will be added to `DOM` after the line

```
this.$el.html(this.template(context));
```

in `render` function is executed.

Since `initialze` method is called when you create a new `instance` of `View` which is always before `render` the `document.getElementById('map-canvas')` does not find the required `element`.

What you should do:

Remove `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);` from `initialize` and add it after `this.$el.html(this.template(context));` line in render.

**NOTE**: Obviously, you need to take care of the `mapOptions` argument that you are passing to `google` API.

Comment: Hello Niranjan, your recommendations were helpful. Unfortunately, I am still not able to get the map to render in the div.

Comment: Where in your code are you instantiating `MapView`? What does this line `module.exports = MapView;` mean? If you are trying to instantiate `MapView` here it should rather be `module.exports = new MapView;`. This would invoke `initialize` and then `render`.